# How to call heightForRowAtIndexPath from a function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to achieve the following effect:

1. User taps once on cell
2. Cell expands if contracted, or contracts if expanded.

So far I have a working function that listens for single taps:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if(indexPath != nil) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        *Call heightForRowAtIndexPath here?*
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

And my `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"runs");
    return 64;
}
```

As far as I've been able to figure out with help from different sites online, I have to call the function somehow between the `[self.tableView beginUpdates]` and `[self.tableView endUpdates]`.
But how do I do this? I'm not that familiar with Xcode or Objective C, so a good explanation would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Aleksander.

Answer (score 5):

You don't call `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` yourself. The tableView will call it. The tableView will call the method after you have send `endUpdates` to it. You have to return a different value from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` after `handleSingleTap:` was called.

You can do this by saving the expanded indexPath in a property (or instance variable), and returning a different value in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` if the requested indexPath matches the saved expanded indexPath.

e.g.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *expandedIndexPath;

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if(indexPath != nil) {
        self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath;
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"runs");
    if (self.expandedIndexPath && [indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath]) {
        // expanded cell
        return 200;
    }
    else {
        return 64;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extremely quick response Matthias! 

(I don't know if this is a problem, but): When I launch the app, "runs" gets printed to the console 4 times. I would like this function to be called ONLY at a single tap. In addition, there are other places where I use the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` too, for example for deleting and rearranging cells.

Is it gonna be a problem? Is this a good solution? Are there better solutions?

Again, thanks :)

Comment: `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` IS called for every cell in your tableView, that's how tableViews work. That is not a problem, it's expected behavior. Remove the log.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[yourIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];` then hight for row will be called appropriately. 
If you call the method above, then no need for `[self.tableView beginUpdate], [self.tableView endUpdate]`